# Get all values in a dropdown select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to get the selected value in an html dropdown menu using jquery.

However, I want to get an array of all values in the dropdown (i.e. and array containing the value of each `<option>` tag in the `<select>`), regardless of what is selected or not.  What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple, using some selectors and an `$.each`:

```
$('select#id_of_select_if_you_want option').each(function(idx, val)
{
    $(val).val(); // here's the value
    $(val).html(); // here's the display text
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of something based on a set of elements, use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var arrayOfValues = $("#mySelect option").map(function() { return this.value; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on gilly3 (someone with the reputation could help?).  His response will give you an object literal, not an array.

If you want an array of values, you can do a map like he suggests, but you need to append the values to a list instead. Here's my version (I'm sure it can be improved):

```
var all_values = [];
$('#dropdown option').map( function() { 
    if (this.value.length) { 
       all_values.push(this.value)
    }
});
```

### EDIT:

It looks like, you can use gilly3's answer, but, if you want to actually use the return as an array, you need to append a .get() method.

```
$('#dropdown option').map( function() {return this.value}).get();
```